# Idiomatic way to get a random number that is different from a previous one?

Tags: random, rust, idioms

Is there a better way to do this in Rust?

```
let mut current_index = rng.gen_range(0, 5);
while current_index == previous_index {
    current_index = rng.gen_range(0, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about idiomatic, but this would avoid the loop:

```
let current_index = (previous_index + rng.gen_range(1, 5)) % 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, perhaps [`SliceRandom::choose_multiple`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.3/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.choose_multiple) or [`SliceRandom::shuffle`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.3/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.shuffle).